# Smack XMPP android Crash on Connecting

Tags: java, android, xmpp, smack

I am using Smack XMPP for an Android app previously every thing was working perfectly smooth except this morning it just starts crashing for no reason.
Here is what I am including in Gradle:

```
compile 'org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-android:4.2.0'
compile 'org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-tcp:4.2.0'
compile 'org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-android-extensions:4.2.0'
```

and the log is printing this error

> java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
>                                                                     at de.measite.minidns.DNSName.from(DNSName.java:287)
>                                                                     at de.measite.minidns.dnssec.DNSSECClient.(DNSSECClient.java:48)
>                                                                     at de.measite.minidns.hla.DnssecResolverApi.(DnssecResolverApi.java:47)
>                                                                     at de.measite.minidns.hla.DnssecResolverApi.(DnssecResolverApi.java:38)
>                                                                     at de.measite.minidns.hla.DnssecResolverApi.(DnssecResolverApi.java:31)
>                                                                     at org.jivesoftware.smack.util.dns.minidns.MiniDnsResolver.(MiniDnsResolver.java:54)
>                                                                     at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
>                                                                     at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:324)
>                                                                     at org.jivesoftware.smack.SmackInitialization.loadSmackClass(SmackInitialization.java:218)
>           private static final DNSName DEFAULT_DLV = DNSName.from("dlv.isc.org");

on this line

```
  XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.Builder config = XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration
                .builder();
```

I searched alot but couldn't find any thing.

Thanks

Comment: I am also getting similar error while accessing XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.builder(); 
It seems like a bug in smack. Visit: https://community.igniterealtime.org/thread/61235 for more info

Comment: I am getting the same issue right now .. how to get it solve ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hi I got this issue too.

The issue comes from one dependency "de.measite.minidns" that pushed an update with a bug. So I fixed it like that by excluding to auto-dependency and including the last stable release. It fixed my problem. Hope it works for you guys

```
    compile ('org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-android:4.2.0') {
      exclude  group:'de.measite.minidns'
    }
    compile ('org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-tcp:4.2.0') {
      exclude  group:'de.measite.minidns'
    }
    compile group: 'de.measite.minidns', name: 'minidns-hla', version: 
    '0.2.2'
```

Comment: can you please share your Gradle as I added the above lines but same issue is happening

Comment: @NooruddinLakhani do I need to add these lines under "dependencies" ??

Comment: @Syeda yes you need to add these in your dependencies

Comment: not working for me :( can you please share you gradle.

Comment: need to add this line too before config "   SmackConfiguration.addDisabledSmackClass("org.jivesoftware.smack.util.dns.minidns.MiniDnsResolver");"

Comment: working for me... from last 5 hours trying to find the answer for this... you come as an angel :)

Answer (score 1):

```
dependencies {

compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
//open due to the need to get offline messages
compile 'org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-extensions:4.2.0'
compile 'org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-im:4.2.0'

compile  ('org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-android:4.2.0') {
    exclude  group:'de.measite.minidns'
}


compile 'org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-experimental:4.2.0'

// Optional for XMPPTCPConnection
compile ('org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-tcp:4.2.0') {
    exclude  group:'de.measite.minidns'
}

compile group: 'de.measite.minidns', name: 'minidns-hla', version:
        '0.2.2'
}
```

Comment: Thanks but need to add "SmackConfiguration.addDisabledSmackClass("org.jivesoftware.s‌​mack.util.dns.minidn‌​s.MiniDnsResolver");‌​" too. Now working :)